# Rate of change of savings.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man saves 20% of his income every year. If his income increases by 10% every year. How much does his savings increase every year ?

Answer (score 2):

To be formal about it, let his salary this year be $s$.  How much does he save?  What is his salary next year in terms of $s$?  How much does he save next year?  Divide this by the savings this year to get the increase.

Comment: I did that. But the increase is not uniform from year to year.

Comment: It is as a percentage.  I believe that is what you are supposed to answer.